# Is there a difference in speed of ice formation between a thick and thin water layer?

Tags: thermodynamics, ice, freezing

Here in the Netherlands we are always trying to get ice as soon as possible so that got me thinking. If you would build a thick layer of ice by spraying a layer of water and wait till its frozen, is it faster to use many small layers or several larger layers. My intuition would say that a small layer would freeze faster and thus so more ice can grow in this same amount of time resulting in the following hypothesis:

**Hypothesis**

Faster total ice growth with many small layers relative to few large layers.

**Heat rejection**

The water will loose heat by convection and radiation to the surroundings via top surface only.

**Example**

Option 1: 20 layers of water each 1 mm

Option 2: 5 layers of water each 4 mm

The area to volume ratio of option 1 is 5 times larger compared to option 2 however the energy needed to freeze the volume also reduced by 5 so this cancels each other out. And should thus not matter for this case.

One reason why this could be the case is that the ice will freeze from the top downwards and so "insulate" the remaining water. However the heat flux through a layer of ice with a thickness of 1-4 mm is much higher than the heat rejection to the surrounding area in normal freezing conditions and is thus not the limiting factor.

There is a small difference between the emissivity of water and ice in the IR-region however I could not find any literature that did research on freezing rate of water with variable water layer height.

Are there any factors that could support my hypothesis or is my intuition wrong?

Comment: "The water will loose heat by convection and radiation to the surroundings via top surface only" this is wrong for radiation , black body radiation is from the volume, see page 3 http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html

Comment: Alright thanks for the link, after reading a little bit more i found that infrared radiation has a optical path much longer than 4 mm in water. Thus heat can be rejected from the entire volume and not only the surface, while with increasing depth less radiation is able to escape the volume. How would one go about and model this heat exchange because almost all books describe thermal radiation as a surface heat flux?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/radfrac.html  . a heat flux can be estimated how much heat per area per second, but it does noe mean it comes just from the surface.